# How to use pydelicious to get bookmark data with user mapping

Tags: python, dataset, mahout-recommender, delicious-api

To experiment with a recommender, I want a good amount of data consisting of users-bookmarks mapping, optionally with some user info, page tags etc. I am trying to use pydelicious to do that but not able to. Through a book I was referring to, I am trying to run get_popular() but every time it results into a result with description as "something went wrong"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this works for me..

Before installing the package, change this line:

`rss = http_request('url').read()`

to:

`rss = http_request('http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss').read()`

It is located at **init**.py

Then you can install the package running `python setup.py install`